# Videojs with Youtube not displaying playlist

Tags: youtube-api, video.js

I am trying to use VideoJS to display a Youtube playlist (not a coded playlist. a Youtube playlist). My implementation is a copy of the example on the videojs-youtube github page: youtube-playlist

The video plays, but there is no playlist. Can anyone direct me?
I can post code. But, I am using the example.
https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube/blob/master/examples/youtube-playlist.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to my issue. But, I found a workaround. Posting here hoping it helps someone else.

Instead of pulling the playlist into videoJS, I wrote a script to pull in the playlist via Google's API, and wrote the output to html on the page.
See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list for info